# Oracle: Rename column gives "ORA-00903: invalid table name" error even when no constraint or index is there

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, table-rename

```
RENAME COLUMN table-Name.simple-Column-Name TO simple-Column-Name
```

When i try to rename column i am getting following error message on all columns:

```
RENAME COLUMN EMP_NEW.EMPLOYEE_ID TO EMPLOYEEID
Error report -
ORA-00903: invalid table name
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Following is version

```
Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.1.0  Production"
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
```

Any suggestion how to resolve this issue? (Note i have created structure from some existing table and not copied anything i.e no index, no constraint nothing, so it is simple create)

Comment: @user7294900: Nothing

Comment: Syntax to rename the column name is `ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME old_column_name TO new_column_name`

Answer (score 8):

Correct Syntax is

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN old_name TO new_name;
```

Use following. but ensure EMP_NEW table is present in the schema you have used to logon

```
ALTER TABLE EMP_NEW RENAME COLUMN EMPLOYEE_ID TO EMPLOYEEID;
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Don't use this syntax, this is [derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/rrefsqljrenamecolumnstatement.html) syntax, use @Gro answer (`alter table`)

Make sure table not in different scheme than user, or use scheme name.

Also make sure there aren't any [open cursors that reference the column](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljrenamecolumnstatement.html)

> Restriction: The RENAME COLUMN statement is not allowed if there are any open cursors that reference the column that is being altered.

Comment: i am able to do it using alter but not rename :(. Even i dropped table and created again

Comment: @fatherazrael alter table is the standard way to *alter* table

Comment: @fatherazrael - As [the Oracle SQL reference states](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9021.htm#SQLRF01608): *"Use the RENAME statement to rename a table, view, sequence, or private synonym"* So not column.

Comment: @APC so statement valid until Oracle 10g only?

Comment: Nope. Not RENAME A TO B did not work with columns even in 10g. From [the 10g SQL ref](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9019.htm#i2064929); *"You cannot use this statement directly to rename columns. However, you can rename a column using the ALTER TABLE ... rename_column_clause. "*